# Do C++ formatting libraries generally fall back to *sprintf for numeric formatting?

Tags: c++, formatting, string-formatting, iostream, fastformat

I am wondering whether "all" C++ formatting libraries eventually fall back to a `*sprintf` function to format numbers.

I am asking this because:

- Looking at the iostreams library that comes with Visual C++, I can see that numbers input into a stream will eventuall be formatted with `sprintf_s`.
- Boost.Format just uses the available iostreams library as far as I can tell.
- [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/) eventually uses `vsprintf` to format a number.

So, are there iostreams implementations that do *not* use *sprintf and do the formatting themselves? Are there other formatting libraries that do *not* forward formatting of numbers to *sprintf family of functions?

I would appreciate answers in the form of:

- No: implementation XY uses ABC to format numbers
- Yes: all other (e.g. iostreams) *implementations I know* (X, Y, Z) also forward number formatting to stdio, because ...

Please avoid overly speculative answers.

Comment: Just looking statistically, due to the options on formatting libraries and forms of numeric formatting, it is highly improbable that this happens...

Comment: This is implementation dependent. How can you expect a conclusive answer such as "yes, they all do"?

Comment: All is very, very broad and hard to answer correctly: there might always be one where the statement doesn't hold. I like the formulation of 'all others *I know*' much better.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised if they did; formatting a `double` is much harder than it appears at first glance. I say this because I know that Tcl (OK, not C++) now doesn't use `sprintf()` for this in normal circumstances, and that it took a lot of code — including a full multi-precision arithmetic library — to do that change.

Comment: Interesting -- whether this question is broad and hard to answer correctly depends what the answer actually is. Answering "no" is easy if you happen to know a counter-example, answering "yes" is either very difficult (to cover all significant implementations and for that matter all third-party string formatting libraries), or very subjective since it just depends which implementations you happen to know about.

Comment: @Donal - could you please add that comment as an answer before the hypocrites ;-) close the question. I think it's great info! (Although speculative.)

Comment: @SteveJessop: so we can now safely answer 'No' :)

Comment: @sehe: yep, I think your answer confirms that it is a real question. Classic example of people voting to close because they don't know the answer and hence assume it can't be answered, although this time with some philosophical grounding ;-)

Comment: From my point of view the close is entirely proper. "Generally" renders the question ill-defined. An all or nothing version would be either trivial (if no) or highly fragile (if yes), and a "which ones do" version would be a make-a-list question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost Spirit doesn't use *printf, as can be seen from the code ([real.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/real.hpp) and [int.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/int.hpp)) and the benchmarks for e.g. ints and doubles.

The benchmark pits Boost Spirit Karma's generators against Boost.Format against sprintf and std::stringstream. Only for gcc compilers does the performance of sprintf come close in that benchmark. Otherwise, Boost Spirit is the clear winner.

[image]

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/performance_measurements/numeric_performance.html

Answer (score 1):

No, for example [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) has its own implementation of integer and floating-point formatting which is much faster than common implementations of `sprintf`. These are the results of a double to string formatting benchmark ([dtoa-benchmark](https://github.com/fmtlib/dtoa-benchmark)) on one platform:

[image: benchmark results]

As you can see {fmt} is ~20x faster than `sprintf` here.

Integer formatting is [also faster](https://www.zverovich.net/2020/06/13/fast-int-to-string-revisited.html) but not as dramatically (up to 6-7x on Linux and macOS):

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of {fmt}.

Comment: Link very appreciated. One quick question (a point that irks me with FastFormat): Do you support wchar_t and char strings in the same module? How are they handled?

Comment: @MartinBa: At the moment the library supports only char strings, but it should be relatively easy to handle wchar_t as well by parameterizing on character type similarly to how it is done with std::basic_string. I plan to add this functionality soon. Or do you mean that you want to mix char and wchar_t strings during formatting like Format("{0}") << L"wide string"?

Comment: No, I didn't mean mixing in the same expression -- while it may be nice, it wakes the encoding demons :-) -- just plain simple support for char and wchar_t like with std iostreams.

Comment: wchar_t strings are fully supported now.