# Boost Spirit : how to convert basic types?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Suppose I have a `std::string` attribute, but for ease-of-parsing, I'd like to use `qi::int_` or `qi::double_`.

**Is there an easy way to do the conversion as a semantic action**?

I tried something like this:

```
 std::stringstream ss; 
 my_int_as_str = qi::int_ [ ref(ss)<<_1; _val=ss.str() ];
```

but this wouldn't even compile.

**EDIT - attempt with sehe's answer below**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi=boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx=boost::phoenix;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string test="123";
    std::string result;

    // 1. qi::raw[ qi::int_ ]       works
    // 2. qi::lexeme[ qi::int_ ]    doesn't
    // 3. qi::as_string[ qi::int_ ] doesn't
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> my_int_as_str = 
                   qi::raw[ qi::int_ ];
    parse( test.cbegin(), test.cend(), my_int_as_str, result );

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    std::string test_vector="456 789";
    std::vector<std::string> result_vector;

    // 4. qi::raw[ qi::int_ ]       won't compile
    // 5. qi::lexeme[ qi::int_ ]    won't compile
    // 6. qi::as_string[ qi::int_ ] doesn't
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,std::vector<std::string>(),qi::space_type> 
            my_int_as_str_vector = qi::lexeme[ qi::int_ ];

    phrase_parse(test_vector.cbegin(),test_vector.cend(),
            my_int_as_str_vector,qi::space,result_vector);

    for(auto& string: result_vector)
        std::cout << string << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`attr_cast`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/attr_cast.html) by specializing [`transform_attribute`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/transform.html) for your types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi=boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx=boost::phoenix;


namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{

    template <>
    struct transform_attribute<std::string, int, qi::domain>
    {
        typedef int type;
        static int pre(std::string& d) { return 0; }//not useful in this case but required to avoid compiler errors
        static void post(std::string& val, int const& attr) //`val` is the "returned" string, `attr` is what int_ parses
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << attr;
            val= ss.str();
        }
        static void fail(std::string&) {}
    };
}}}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string test="123";
    std::string test_vector="456 789";

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,std::string()> my_int_as_str = qi::attr_cast(qi::int_);
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,std::vector<std::string>(),qi::space_type> my_int_as_str_vector= *qi::attr_cast(qi::int_);

    std::string result;
    std::vector<std::string> result_vector;

    parse(test.cbegin(),test.cend(),my_int_as_str,result);
    phrase_parse(test_vector.cbegin(),test_vector.cend(),my_int_as_str_vector,qi::space,result_vector);


    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    for(auto& string: result_vector)
        std::cout << string << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

If you really need/want to use [semantic actions](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html) the simplest alternative would be to define a function taking an int as argument and returning a string (this is simpler than the `attr_cast` alternative but it is also slower, nearly twice the time in my really simple benchmarks):

```
std::string semantic_transform(int i)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<i;
    return ss.str();
}
...
std::string string_semantic;
qi::parse(test.cbegin(),test.cend(),qi::int_[&semantic_transform],string_semantic);
std::cout << string_semantic << std::endl;
```

Comment: excellent - tyvm for the detailed answer (benchmark comment is also good to know)

Comment: +1 for a boatload of excellent information and techniques. However, I'm going to prefer my own answer for this particular task :)

Answer (score 6):

Builtin way:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> my_int_as_str = 
       qi::as_string [ qi::int_ ];
```

For this particular simple case, `qi::raw` or `qi::lexeme` would have worked equally well since they both expose source-iterator pairs, which have builtin *assignment-to-attribute* for `std::string`

**Elaborating:**

```
my_int_as_str = qi::lexeme [ qi::int_ ]; // equivalent
my_int_as_str = qi::raw [ qi::int_ ];    // idem
```

Comment: +1 wow - this is even better - could you elaborate with an example on your `qi::raw` and `qi::lexeme` comment?  I will try out your example - ty.

Comment: ty - I attempted 6 ways (as_string, lexeme, raw) by (std::string,std::vector<std::string>) and the only one I could get working was raw with std::string.  There must be some subtle differences between the three (code is in OP edit)...  I will try to google some docs.

Comment: +1 using qi::raw. It is way simpler and infinitely faster (more than 40 times faster with msvc11 and around 8 times faster with g++ 4.7.1). The other options do the same as my_int_as_str=qi::int_ convert the int to a char ({).

Comment: Apparently most of the difference is due to the use of stringstream([interesting blog about it](http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/02/07/cpp-convert-int-to-string-speed/)). If I change the contents of the `post` function to `karma::generate(std::back_inserter(val),karma::int_,attr);` the times are comparable (still a little slower than `qi::raw`, but much faster than the original).

Comment: @llonesmiz See [Do C++ formatting libraries generally fall back to *sprintf for numeric formatting?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7684912/85371) for performance of Karma vs. sstream. Of course `qi::raw` should be fastest, because it does **no conversion**. It would be faster still if you could use `+qi::digit` instead. For blazing performance, you could just return the `boost::iterator_pair<Iterator>` and delay the construction of the string (assuming forward iterators, not input iterators). This, basically, is what Spirit Lex does for tokens.